# How to run JUint Test with AndroidJUnitRunner

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing

I want to write a JUnit test for some code that only needs an Android Context, but i don't want a mock i want a real context to pass to my Object.

I want to initialize a Realm instance.

Answer (score -1):

The following example is google tutorial

It shows how you might create a unit test that uses a mock Context object.

To add a mock object to your local unit test using this framework, follow this programming model:

```
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class UnitTestSample {

    private static final String FAKE_STRING = "HELLO WORLD";

    @Mock
    Context mMockContext;

    @Test
    public void readStringFromContext_LocalizedString() {
        // Given a mocked Context injected into the object under test...
        when(mMockContext.getString(R.string.hello_word))
                .thenReturn(FAKE_STRING);
        ClassUnderTest myObjectUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest(mMockContext);

        // ...when the string is returned from the object under test...
        String result = myObjectUnderTest.getHelloWorldString();

        // ...then the result should be the expected one.
        assertThat(result, is(FAKE_STRING));
    }
}
```

[Building Local Unit Tests](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html)

Comment: I am trying to initialize a Realm instance, so i cant used a mocked Context